# How to create a pop up remainder message on input dialog in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

[image: sample figure]

How can I create a reminder message as shown in the figure for instance the matrix size enter must greater than 30 and until the input is satisfy this condition ONLY the OK button on the dialog box can be pressed. In other words, only satisfy the condition only the input can be read into the program.

thank you everyone for the helps.

Source code for the dialog above:

prompt = {'Enter matrix size:','Enter colormap name:'};

dlg_title = 'Input for peaks function';

num_lines = 1;

def = {'20','hsv'};

answer = inputdlg(prompt,dlg_title,num_lines,def);

Answer (score 0):

For the reminder, just set a tooltip property...

For Ok button, check that input satisfies required conditions in the callback function and only accept the dialog if it does

Comment: if h is a handle to your line edit, then set(h,'ToolTip','>30');

Comment: Really sorry because I've tried it but I really make it out, can you provide an easy example. @llya Kobelvskiy

Comment: Please post the source code for the dialog screenshot of which you displayed above then :)

Comment: I have edited my post..thank so much for the helps @llya Kobelevskiy

Comment: I see. I'm not 100% sure if you can customize inputdlg that much, however, what you can definitely do is to create your own dialog with desired properties - you can start guide, drug and drop required items like line edits, text and buttons, set properties of each item there and assign callback to buttons... To start guide, simply type guide in matlab command line, select gui with uicontrols, and go from there